# How To Obtain Username, First Name Or Last Name Of A Telegram User With Python-Telegram-Bot?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm Creating A Telegram Bot Using [Python-Telegram-Bot](http://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot)

I Know That `update.message.chat_id` Returns The User's Chat ID, But I Need To Know How To Get User's Username Or First Name And/Or Last Name.

I've Found [This](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getchatmember) On Telegram's Documentation But I Don't Know How To Use It ( I Tried `bot.getChat(update.message.chat_id)` But No Result)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

All infomation about user (as username, id, first/last name and profile photos) available from [telegram.User](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/telegram.html#telegram.User) object. You can easily get it using [telegram.Message](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/telegram.message.html?highlight=message)

```
user = update.message.from_user
print('You talk with user {} and his user ID: {} '.format(user['username'], user['id']))
```

Comment: I want to add one thing.


Sometimes, if the bot flow allows user to navigate by pressing some InlineButtons, user might not send a message. So to understand user info, 


`update.callback_query.from_user` method can be used too. According to the nature of the interaction, a different method might be needed.

Answer (score 12):

You can use the json file and access information such as username, ID, etc. You can print this file yourself for information about the json file. See the example below.

```
# pip install python-telegram-bot==12.0.0
from telegram.ext import Updater
from telegram.ext import CommandHandler
updater = Updater('token')

def start(bot, update):
    # print('json file update : ' ,update)
    # print("json file bot : ', bot)
    chat_id = update.message.chat_id
    first_name = update.message.chat.first_name
    last_name = update.message.chat.last_name
    username = update.message.chat.username
    print("chat_id : {} and firstname : {} lastname : {}  username {}". format(chat_id, first_name, last_name , username))
    bot.sendMessage(chat_id, 'text')

start_command = CommandHandler('start',start)
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(start_command)
updater.start_polling()
updater.idle()
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your python version on your terminal or cmd by typing==> ***python --version***
If you are using Pycharm as your IDE then, do the following:

1. Install Telegram API using this command on your terminal ==>***pip3 install pyTelegramBotAPI***
2. Afterwards, you can import the telebot
3. Then run the following commands below on your terminal
4. Install ***pip install telegram*** via terminal
5. Install ***pip install python-telegram-bot*** via terminal
6. Now import from telegram.ext import *

Then use the following code below to get the user information from the chat:

```
import telebot

from telegram.ext import *

from creds import API_KEY

shopflipper = telebot.TeleBot(API_KEY, parse_mode=None)

@shopflipper.message_handler(commands=["help", "hello"])
def send_help_message(msg):
        #print(msg) --> this prints out all the information related to the chat
        print(msg.from_user.username)
        username = str(msg.from_user.username)
        #print(username)
       
        shopflipper.reply_to(msg, "Hello")


shopflipper.polling()
```

Answer (score 1):

`update.effective_user.id`

This worked for me in any case, whether it's a callback from inlines or simple MessageHandler, the user id is same.